# How to use Eclipse Mars to connect to Subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-mars

How can I connect to SVN repositories from Eclipse Mars release?

Comment: Thank you for joining StackOverflow! I've just upvoted and voted to close the question at the same time. Why? Because there should be the same questions and you could answer them (the same answer as you've just posted). Or you could post a question and answer it yourself.

Comment: To conform to Stack Overflow standards you must ask a question and then add an answer. Answering the question yourself is fine but you must ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

*[Copied from the original "question" to be a proper SO Q&A]*

1. Install Subversive SVN Team Provider using Eclipse Marketplace. Under options choose what you need from optional software.
2. After restart, you can use **File** > **Import** or the *SVN Repositories* perspective to import project from svn.
3. You Will get prompted. Install the Latest SVNKit (1.8.10)

Comment: Any particular reason to avoid Subclipse?

Comment: I didn't write the answer, so I don't know the author's motivation. I've used both subclipse and subversive and find them to be nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

1. Eclipse Help >>> Install New Software .
2. Provide http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/ site url.
3. type svn , you will find svn clients.

After installing SVN client , if you try to connect to svn repository, you will be asked for connector to be installed. You can select anyone from the list shown.

Once the connectors are installed , restart eclipse. Now you are ready for svn from eclipse.