# Eclipse Mars doesn't show SVN options and views

Tags: eclipse, svn

I need to add SVN plugin to my eclipse. I followed the installa instructions but now I have the plugin installed but not SVN options or views... Why?

[image]
these are my plugins (with SVN!)

[image]

these are my options, and there isn't SVN.

Comment: This is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881733/how-to-use-eclipse-mars-to-connect-to-subversion I had to reinstall eclipse from the beginning

Comment: You should delete this question since there is a duplicate. I can't mark it as a duplicate because the other one's answer was never accepted.

Comment: The problem is that the other is not a question... please answer here ad I will accept it.